# How to index DataFrame by Boolean values in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to index a `DataFrame` using Boolean values, for example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame((100,2), columns = ("a", "b"))
s = x.b > 0
```

How to choose rows where `s` is `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mask = x.b > 0
subset = x[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool_value=x['b']>0
 required_rows=x[bool_value]

 # one line code
 required_rows=x[(x['b']>0)]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with your answer so that others can learn as well.